# average normalised shannon energy for phonocardiography signals

Tags: matlab, signals

I have a code that has to calculate average normalised Shannon energy for phonocardigraphy signals but have a problem with calculating standard deviation. maybe something wrong with my code above this expression. Can somedody help me. please.

```
    function segmentation_Shennon
    close all 
    clear all 

    % Загружаем файл с данными
    [F,Fs] = audioread('1.wav'); 

    pcg = F(:,2); 
    t=0:1/Fs:(length(F)-1)/Fs; 
    %% Нормируем и фильтруем сигнал фильтром Чебышева 1 8го порядка НЧ с частотой среда 882 Гц 
    pcg_filter = chebushev1(pcg,Fs);
    pcg_norm = pcg_filter./abs(max(pcg_filter));
    %рассчитываем энергию Шеннона
    shennon_energy= -((pcg_norm.^2).*log(pcg_norm.^2));
    figure(1)
    plot(t,shennon_energy)

    %рассчитываем усредненную энергию Шеннона в сегменте длительностью 0,02с
    %с перекрытием 0.01 с
    win=0.002*Fs; 
    i=1;
    k=1;
    Es=[];
    Es_t=[];
    P=[];

    while  i<length(pcg_norm)

    for i=i:i+win
    square = pcg_norm(i).^2; 
    Es(k) = -1/win * sum( square .* log(square));
    end
    ES_t(k)=t(i); 
    i=i+round(win/2);
    k=k+1;
    end


% нормируем усреднeнyую энергию Шеннона
M_Es = (mean(Es)); %среднее значение энергии сегмента
S_Es = (std(Es(k-1)));  %стандартное отклонение энергии сегмента
P(k) = (Es(k-1)-M_Es)/S_Es; % Нормированная усредненная энергия Шеннона,
plot(t,P)
```

Comment: I think your question needs some clarifications. What result are you expecting, and what do you actually get? What exactly do you mean by "a problem with calculating standard deviation"? Please consider editing your question to add relevant details.

Comment: The code is barely readable and the comments in Russian do not help much. Yes people can always use a translator to get "The normalized average Shannon energy" out of "Нормированная усредненная энергия Шеннона" but they should not.

Comment: okey you're right.
well, i found in this part the problems, so in case someone will be looking smth the same will post it below
function segmentation_Shennon

Comment: pcg_filter = chebushev1(pcg,Fs);
pcg_norm = pcg_filter/max(abs(pcg_filter));
for i=1:length(pcg_norm) 
    if pcg_norm(i) == 0;
       pcg_norm(i) = 1e-6;
    end
end

shennon_energy= -((pcg_norm.^2).*log(pcg_norm.^2));



win=0.02*Fs; 
i=1;
k=1;
P=[];
peak_t=[];


while i+win<length(pcg_norm)
    square = pcg_norm(i:i+(win)).^2; 
    Es(k) = -1/win * sum( square .* log(square));
    peak_t(k)=t(i); 
i=i+(round(win/2));
k=k+1;
end



M_Es = (mean(Es)); 
S_Es = (std(Es));

for n=1:1:k-1
P(n) = (Es(n)-M_Es)/S_Es;
end
p_norm=P/max(abs(P)); %